# Is and It / is and that. which is correct in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction

Question

Is this correct of usages of (is it) or (is that)

The latest data you have input is it a duplicate entry, because reflects the same poundage's?

Comment: Either can be used and it would be understood, but usually "it" would be used.

Comment: Eh, I can't make sense of the OP's sentence @Peter. Care to explain with an answer?

Comment: Either can be used, but I would tend to use 'that' if I was physically pointing out the entry I was referring to e.g. Is *that* a duplicate entry - because it is showing the same poundage value?

Otherwise I would use 'it' e.g. The latest data you've input - is it a duplicate entry?  Because the poundage value is the same.

Comment: The sentence has several grammatical errors, so *it* vs. *that* should be a minor concern. You need to add what you are trying to say, or add additional context.

Answer (score 1):

As written, they are both wrong.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to say, but better options would be something like

> Is the latest data you have input a duplicate entry?

or

> The latest data you have input - is it a duplicate entry?

("that" would also work here)

Answer (score 0):

The latest data you have input is it a duplicate entry, because reflects the same poundage's?
If this is a spoken; not written question, both it or that can be used. It depends on the context. *that* is as demonstrative pronoun to indicate something distant from the writer or speaker. If the entry is distant, you ask : *Is that a distant duplicate entry?* If it is closer, you ask: *Is this a duplicate entry?* 
However, you may rephrase your sentence in this way. 
*Is the latest data you have input a duplicate entry? Because it reflects the same poundages.*